# How to keep on adding the component on react state change.?

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a simple requirement where there is a `successBar` component

`<successBar msg={"message"}/>`

this one I want to insert to the dom on some state change. lets say we have a state,
`successMessage`, if we set a message in this state, then we need to how the success bar

like:-

```
{
    this.state.successMessage && <SuccessBar msg={this.state.successMessage} />
}
```

the above code works,

here the main requirement is when the `successMessage` is updated it should add a new `<Successbar />` and not replace the previous, bar.
and I don't want to track the previous success msg.

the `<SuccessBar />` component will dismiss itself after a few seconds.

how to achieve this, in react.

Comment: U can learn stack, I think this is an array of <SuccessBar /> component. this link can help u: https://tinloof.com/blog/how-to-create-react-notifications-with-0-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You can have an Array with the `SuccessBar` components you want to render, and `push` to that array on every `successMessage` change.

Like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function SuccessBar({ msg }) {
  return <div>{msg}</div>;
}

export default function App() {
  const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState("");

  const [successComponents, setSuccessComponents] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (successMessage) {
      setSuccessComponents((prevArray) => [
        ...prevArray,
        <SuccessBar msg={successMessage} />
      ]);
    }
  }, [successMessage]);

  return (
      successComponents.map((Component) => Component)
  );
}
```